# Review of Excel Stock Simulator

Tags: equities, simulations, excel

I am currently a senior in high school and I built a stock simulator using knowledge gained from a semester of AP Statistics. I was wondering if someone could tell me if my simulation is legit/reasonable!

Here is the Download Link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/llebsb868k06nbz/Simple%20Stock%20Simulator%20Dropbox.xlsm?dl=0

The green cells are for inputs and you can run the ScaleAxes macro (press Alt F8 and hit run) to auto format the stock price graph.

Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure that the source that provides the inputs  (expected return and volatility) uses the same formulas as in your simulation.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question!